# Transition to Google Cloud SQL from the Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

I have a decent sized database on Google App Engine and I am using the current Datastore as well as the Blobstore for photos.  I am just curious about the advantages and then difficulties in transitioning to the Google Cloud SQL.

Google says that it is faster for reads and writes but doesn't say how it compares on cost.  Also is either one more scalable?  Right now everything is working well on the HRD but I am wondering if it will be worth it down the road to transition to GC SQL.

Comment: I'm unaware of Google-made comparisons between the datastore and Cloud SQL regarding read and write speed. Do you have a link?

Comment: on second thought it looks like they are comparing it to a previous version of the GC SQL but I was talking about the second and third bullet points:  http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/11/get-started-at-no-cost-with-faster.html

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely comparing to previous versions of Cloud SQL. That isn't to say reads/writes can't be faster with Cloud SQL than with the datastore, but generally the choice between one or the other comes down to other things (familiarity of implementation, scalability, workload, compatibility, etc.)

Comment: Okay thanks for clearing that up.  And in terms of scalability is either one better or is that just dependent on my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this presentation from Google I/O informative: 
[SQL vs NoSQL: Battle of the Backends](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRoy6I4gKWU). Spoiler: Datastore is more scalable, but Cloud SQL is better for apps that don't need scalability.